# Prevent iframe from reloading when changing the src attribute?

Tags: html, angular, iframe

I'm using Angular (not important for this problem but explains the syntax) and have something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button (click)="setIframeSrc('http://mypage.com/page1')">Page 1</button>
<button (click)="setIframeSrc('http://mypage.com/page2')">Page 2</button>

<iframe [src]="iframeSource"></iframe>
```

**Typescript:**

```
setIframeSrc(url) {
    this.iframeSource = url;
}
```

The site "mypage.com" is my own website that is a SPA application, meaning there is no page reloads happening when going from Page 1 to Page 2.

Current behaviour

1. I click the "Page 1" button
2. The iframe loads in `mypage.com/page1`
3. I click the "Page 2" button
4. The iframe reloads and loads in `mypage.com/page2`

Wanted behaviour:

1. I click the "Page 1" button
2. The iframe loads in `mypage.com/page1`
3. I click the "Page 2" button
4. **A navigation to `mypage.com/page2` occurs in the iframe without reloading the whole iframe**

When I click the two buttons I want "mypage.com" to only load on the first click and every subsequent click should not reload the iframe but just navigate inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parent site is on the same domain as child sites (mypage.com) you can try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45828201/10672983

If you have a cross-domain problems, you can try to simple messaging system parent-> child:

[How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Parent:

```
 myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage('/page2', '*');
```

Child:

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
   router.navigateByUrl(e.data)
};
```